# two different ways of defining virtual inheritance in C++

Tags: c++

What is the semantic difference(s) between the following two:

```
class Storable{};
class Transmitter: public virtual Storable{};
class Receiver: public virtual Storable{};
class Radio: public Transmitter, public Receiver{};
```

vs.

```
class Storable{};
class Transmitter: public Storable{};
class Receiver: public Storable{};
class Radio: public virtual Transmitter, public virtual Receiver{};
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9

Answer (score 2):

The first indicates that `Transmitter` and `Receiver` will share a common `Storable` sub-object; so that `Radio` will only contain one.

The second indicates that they will each have their own `Storable` sub-object; so that `Radio` will contain two. (The virtual inheritance of `Transmitter` and `Receiver` doesn't make any difference to `Radio`; it would only make a difference to classes that inherit further from it).

Comment: OK, if `class Storable{};
class Transmitter: public Storable{};
class Receiver: public Storable{};` as defined, how to make `Radio` only have one `Storable` sub-object?

Comment: @QiangLi: Make `Transmitter` and `Receiver` inherit virtually from `Storable`, as in your first example. You can't do it without changing their definitions.

Comment: @QiangLi: you cannot. You cannot alter the definition of a class after the fact. Either it is defined to share or not.